# Docker Nginx Proxy Pass Game Server

Tags: docker, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I'm trying to setup an Nginx docker container to run my personal website as well as my game servers on a digital ocean droplet.  I want it so that `example.com` is the personal website, and `gmod.example.com` is the game server. The personal website works fine, and I was able to get a sample node server working as a debugging attempt for the game server config, but the game server just doesn't work.  I'm not sure what's wrong with my configuration.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    reverseproxy:
        container_name: reverseproxy
        hostname: reverseproxy
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
          - 27015:27015
        volumes:
          - ~/test/nginx/:/etc/nginx/
          - ~/test/sslcerts/:/etc/letsencrypt/
          - ~/test/websites:/var/www/
          - /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem
        depends_on:
          - gmod
    gmod:
        container_name: gmod
        hostname: gmod
        build:
            context: ~/test/game_servers/gmod
```

example.com.conf:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2; #Certbot
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; #Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; #Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; #Certbot

        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
        #include /etc/nginx/snippets/header.conf;
        #include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root /var/www/example.com;

        index index.html;
        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/snippets/header.conf;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        #for certbot renewal
        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /data/letsencrypt;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        if ($host = www.example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } #certbot

        if ($host = example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } #certbot

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 404; # certbot
}
```

gmod.example.com.conf:

```
upstream gmod {
        server gmod:27015;
}

server {
        listen 27015;
        listen [::]:27015;
        server_name gmod.example.com www.gmod.example.com;

        access_log /etc/nginx/logs/gmod.access;
        error_log /etc/nginx/logs/gmod.error;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://gmod;
        }
}
```

Dockerfile for game server:

```
FROM cm2network/steamcmd:root

ENV STEAMAPPID 4020
ENV STEAMAPPDIR /home/steam/gmod
ENV MAP gm_flatgrass
ENV GAMEMODE sandbox

# Run Steamcmd and install Gmod
RUN set -x \
        && "${STEAMCMDDIR}/steamcmd.sh" \
                +login anonymous \
                +force_install_dir ${STEAMAPPDIR} \
                +app_update ${STEAMAPPID} validate \
                +quit

USER steam

WORKDIR $STEAMAPPDIR

VOLUME $STEAMAPPDIR

# Set the entrypoint:
# 1) Update the server
# 2) Run the server
ENTRYPOINT ${STEAMCMDDIR}/steamcmd.sh \
                +login anonymous +force_install_dir ${STEAMAPPDIR} +app_update ${STEAMAPPID} +quit \
                && ${STEAMAPPDIR}/srcds_run \
                        -game garrysmod -maxplayers 16 +gamemode ${GAMEMODE} +map ${MAP}
```

With the current setup, when I navigate to gmod.example.com, it gives me a 404 (this is expected given the config, but eventually, I want it to be working).  Navigating to gmod.example.com:27015 gives a `502 Bad Gateway` in the browser. The access logs show nothing happening except when I hit the bad gateway.  The game client just reports there are no servers at all. Any help would be much appreciated. Ideally, the answer is extensible, right now I'm only running one server, but in the future, I'd like multiple of different kinds of running.

In digital ocean, I have the A records for `example.com`, `test.example.com`, and `gmod.example.com` (along with each of those with the www. prefix).  They're all pointing to the droplet as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to change your configuration, as your trying to communicate with the game server through HTTP web protocol when what you actually need is to communicate using UDP/TCP.

This is done using the `ngx_stream_core_module` see more [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html)

Also, FYI if you're using the Nginx pre-built install you don't need to do anything, just
add `stream {}` into your `nginx.conf` file outside of `http {}`

`nginx.conf`

```
http {
    #web stuff here e.g. Website config
}


stream {        
    server {
        listen 27015;    
        proxy_pass gmod;
    }

    upstream gmod {
        server 127.0.0.1:27015;
    }  

}
```